# Installshield setup crashes while trying to call managed code DLL

Tags: c#, installshield

I have created an installshield project. In that I have created a custom action using "Calling public method in a managed assembly". code in the DLL is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
         public string MyFunc(int flag)
        {


             System.Management.ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
             ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
             string result = "";
             foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol)
                {
                 if (Convert.ToInt32(strt["MediaType"]) != 12) { continue; }
                 if (Convert.ToInt32(strt["DriveType"]) != 3) { continue; }
                 if (Convert.ToString(strt["Name"]).ToLower() != "c:") { continue; }
                 result += "VolumeSerialNumber   : " + Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]) + Environment.NewLine;
                 result = Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) break;

                }

                return result;


        }
    }
}
```

Whenever installshield tries to call this method MyFunc, It is not able to find dependency System.managment.dll and it crashes. I verified that the setup crashes due to this issue only as if I comment the code that is using system.managment.dll and simply returns a hard coded string things works fine.

In installshield I have also added System.Management.dll as dependency to custom action created in ISClrwap table. I also added in installshield prerequisites I have downloaded .Net Framework 4.0.

I have searched lot of forms but not able to figure out the solution to this issue.

Comment: Maybe try using Fuslogvw.exe, see if it can tell you why System.Management.dll is not getting loaded.

Comment: Does this code run on the system when it's not part of the install? I suspect that WMI is not always enabled by default on all systems. For example search -enable wmi server 2008- and other OS versions if the code fails in a normal interactive user app.